# How to covert PDF to text or json file by using python in mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

Note:while i execute some of the pdf its give the txt output. But idont know why its giving error for other pdf

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('first.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print page_content.encode('utf-8')

output:
lab>python 1.py 
!"#$%&'(&$')*
+)&'(&$')*
 ,-.-/-01-234"5/3-67893:3;<"0-31"0=-/>7?8"0
 @5A23B5"?-3."/38C3@-/=-/3
D11"50?3E707F-/23G8H7IJ567/3E3KL678923=8H7IJ567/M6N/7<8>I>?-6>M1"63O<"0-23PQ)3*()R'++SSST
U-7/3@8/:E7V76#
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Its giving binary data insted of text data :(

Comment: There are 2 kinds of PDFs - text and image. What kind of PDFs are you using in your code? The binary output you are getting seems like the content of a PDF (open a pdf in your text editor, you'll know). Also, please specify the error you are getting as @Rloqvist says.

Comment: @Rloqvist i am not getting error but while i am using this code for PDF 1.4 version its gives simplay binary output.